# how can i select input second in this ajax code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

my **form**

```
<form action="javascript:alert( 'success!' );">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit">
 </div>
</form>
```

my **ajax code**

```
<script>
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    if ( $( "input:first" ).val() === "correct" &&  $( "input:second" ).val() === "test"  )  {
        $( "span" ).text( "Validated..." ).show();
        return;
    }

    $( "span" ).text( "Not valid!" ).show().fadeOut( 10000 );
    event.preventDefault();

    /// set here your ajax code
});
```

how can i select password field.
2.this method is easly hackable?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type="password"]')
```

**OR**

```
$('input[name="password"]')
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($('input[type="password"]').val())
  alert($('input[name="password"]').val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="password" value="test">
  <input type="submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such selector `:second` but you can use it with `.next()`:

```
if ( $( "input:first" ).val() === "correct" &&  
     $( "input:first" ).next().val() === "test"  )  {
```

other options are:

1. With `.next()`
2. Using `:eq()` or `.eq()`.
3. with `.index()` etc.

Comment: OP never mentioned he can not use `id` so best option would be using `id` attributes..

Comment: @RayonDabre agreed! i suppose to mention that also just thought too much about the code.

Comment: @RayonDabre  then what should i do?